# Can anyone provide me a step-by-step proof for proving a function IS onto/surjective?

Tags: functions

I've seen the definition, I've seen several examples and anti-examples (e.g. the typical x squared example).  I get the idea, but I can't seem to find a proof for proving that a function IS onto, with proper explanation start to finish.

Given:

- $f: R$ $\rightarrow$ $R$
- $f(x) = -3x + 4$

Prove that the above function is "onto."  I know that this IS onto, but what would a dry, stone cold proof look like for this, that says like Step 1 with justification, step 2 with justification, and so on?

The closest thing I could find to what I'm looking for: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/sp2009/lectures/lect_15_supp.pdf in Section 3.  It says to prove that g(x) = x - 8 is onto, and it does so by setting x to be (y + 8).  But...why choose that value?  What formula or strategy is there for determining what x should be?  It appears as though you want x to be whatever will get rid of other stuff (+8 against a -8).

So with some basic algebra, I *think* I can set x to $-\frac13$y + $\frac43$.  And this is valid by the definition of real numbers, yes?  This properly cancels everything out so that f(x) = y.  Is that really the end of the proof?.....or am I way off the track?

Comment: This is the end of the proof. You need to proof, that for every $y\in\mathbb R$, there is some $x\in\mathbb R$, such that $f(x)=y$. That's what you did.

Comment: But it's very easy to figure out what x should be in something so simple.  In this case just by looking at "-3x + 4" you can "eyeball" it to figure that you need -1/3y + 4/3.  But how do you formally arrive at that?

Comment: In a formal proof, you don't need to justify how you found $x$, you just need to show (formally) that $f(x)=y$, maybe show step by step, that this really cancels out. (In order to find that $x$, equating the function with $y$ and solving for $x$ is a good idea in general.)

Comment: Ah...so, that really is all there is to it then...No wonder I couldn't find what I was looking for, because I was overthinking it in terms of, "I need to prove every single little step."

Answer (score 1):

The key word is **inverse** of a function.

If $y$ represents the value after having $f$ applied on $x$, then we have
$$y=-3x+4\,.$$
Now we can imagine that quantities $x$ and $y$ *vary together*, bound together by the above equation.

To find the inverse function of $f$, we need to express $x$ by means of $y$:
$$y-4=-3x\\ 3x=4-y\\ x=\frac{4-y}3\,.$$
Since we could do it in a unique way, $f$ is not only surjective, it is also *bijective*.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to prove that a function is surjective is to take each value $y$ and find - any way you can - a value of $x$ with $f(x)=y$. If you succeed for every possible value of $y$, then you have proved that $f$ is surjective.

So we take $x=-\cfrac 13y+ \cfrac 43$ as you suggest. This is well-defined (no division by zero, for example)

Then $f(x)=-3x+4=-3\left(-\cfrac 13y+ \cfrac 43\right)+4=y-4+4=y$

So your formula covers every $y$ at once. And because you have covered every $y$ you can say that you have a surjection.